# How to call an external page using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to call an external page (which I can control) from another domain (which I cannot control). Below is the script I use to call, but the page is not being called.

```
    $(function () {

    var val = window.location.hostname;
    alert(val);

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://somedomain.com/validate.aspx/validfunction",
        data: "{domain: '" + val + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);

        },


        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

        }
    });
});
```

No idea, why I cannot call. Is there any better way to call the page. Please advice.

Comment: do you want to say your `GET` request to `URL` doesn't work?

Comment: Does server expect `JSON` as `data`? Is `error` handler called?

Comment: can you provide us the parameter you are sending that URL.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan There is some code which executes and display a div with certain contents from the external url to the third party domain. The only parameter we pass is the third party domain to validate, whether the same domain is in our database. If it is there, display the contents

Comment: Is remote api CORS enabled? If not that will show as error in browser console and you can also inspect the headers to see if they exist

Answer (score 1):

Use `XMLHttpRequest` object to make a request like below

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The request is obviously `GET` and 'URL' is the url you want to execute/open. The 3rd parameter is for async request, it can be either true or false.

Create a div element for eg: with id - `result` and append the result received in `#result` element, you can simply use this in the next line:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

`contentType` is set to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` though value of `data` option, for example

```
"{domain: '1'}"
```

is not valid `JSON`. Property names should be surrounded by double quotes.

Create a `javascript` plain object, populate with properties, values, then pass `javascipt` plain object to `JSON.stringify()`, set `data` as valid `JSON` result.

See [`$.ajax([settings])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

> **contentType** (default: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded`;=UTF-8'`)
>
> Type: `Boolean` or `String`
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to `$.ajax()`, then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
>   the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
>   the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests,
>   setting the content type to anything other than
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`
>   will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
>   server

```
$(function () {

    var val = window.location.hostname;
    alert(val);
    var data = JSON.stringify({"domain": val});
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://somedomain.com/validate.aspx/validfunction",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },    
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);    
        }
    });
});
```

You can alternatively try to use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) both with and without `"?callback=?"` appended to URL.

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the `jsonp` data type in `$.ajax()` for more details.

```
var val = window.location.hostname;
var data = JSON.stringify({"domain": val});
$.getJSON("http://somedomain.com/validate.aspx/validfunction?callback=?", data)
.then(function(data) {
  // do stuff with `data`
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

Comment: @Gops Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net, or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Whenever we request web-method from ajax method, it should be type 'POST' and for cross domain the datatype is 'JSONP'. The web method should return data as in JSON format.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://somedomain.com/validate.aspx/validfunction",
    data: "{domain: '" + val + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);

    },


    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

    }
});
```